# How to refresh chekout page woocommerce 3 with AJAX after selecting the shipping method

Tags: woocommerce

I use hooks to remove or return payment fields, depending on which delivery method is selected.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_address_fields', 20, 1 );
// Our hooked in function - $address_fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields) {
    unset($address_fields['company']);
    unset($address_fields['address_2']);
    unset($address_fields['country']);
    unset($address_fields['state']);
    unset($address_fields['postcode']);
    $shipping_method ='local_pickup:1'; // Set the desired shipping method to hide the checkout field(s).
    global $woocommerce;
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];

    if ($chosen_shipping == $shipping_method) {
    // Delete address_1 field
        unset($address_fields['address_1']);
    } else {
    // Return address_1 field
        $address_fields['city'] = array(
            'type'      => 'text',
            'label'     => __('House number and street name', 'woocommerce'),
            'required'  => true,
            'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
            'clear'     => true
        );
    }

    return $address_fields;
}
```

After changing the delivery method, I need to reload the order page with AJAX, in order to delete or return the address_1